# O que torna Kotlin uma linguagem mais rápida que o Java?

Tags: java, desempenho, característica-linguagem, kotlin

Já li em alguns artigos que o *Kotlin* é mais rápido que Java, porém nenhum deles exemplifica o motivo disso.

- *[...] Tão rápido quanto Java"*. [Kotlin - Evolua seu código Java (TDC-2016) Alex Magalhaes](https://pt.slideshare.net/Alex_Magalhaes/kotlin-evolua-seu-cdigo-java-tdc2016-alex-magalhaes)
- *[...] O Kotlin deve compilar rapidamente, coexistir com o Java e corrigir alguns dos piores problemas que ocupam o tempo dos desenvolvedores Java* -  [Nove linguagens de programação que vale a pena manter no radar](http://cio.com.br/tecnologia/2017/07/14/nove-linguagens-de-programacao-que-vale-a-pena-manter-no-radar/).
- *[...] um aplicativo Kotlin é tão rápido quanto um Java equivalente* - [Kotlin: A nova linguagem oficial para desenvolvimento Android](https://www.treinaweb.com.br/blog/kotlin-a-nova-linguagem-oficial-para-desenvolvimento-android/)

O que pode ser visto em primeiro momento, seria pela questão da quantidade de linhas de código para realizar tal procedimento ou ação. O *Kotlin* aparentemente reduz estas linhas (visualmente) em relação ao Java.

Seria mesmo a redução de *bytecodes* ou teria algo mais em especial para que fique mais rápida? O que torna *Kotlin* uma linguagem mais rápida que o Java? Se tem código Java dentro do *Kotlin*, por causa da interoperabilidade, ou vice-versa, isso quer dizer que usa o meio termo em relação ao tempo?

Comment: Não existe resposta certa pro assunto. O kotlin é uma linguagem diferente do java, mais moderna e simplificada, em termos de comparação podemos comparar o Objective-C (Usado pra IOS) e o Swift, ambas linguagens chegam a um resultado específico porém o swift é o futuro, por ser mais simplificado, expressivo em termo de código e assim aumenta a produtividade. O Java é uma linguagem que poucos gostam ele no android até o momento era a única opção porém certamente isso deve mudar assim como aconteceu no IOS. No momento o ideal é estudar ambas mas certamente Kotlin é o futuro do android.

Comment: Cite onde diz isso porque pra mim é novidade.

Comment: @bigown justamente por isso. Eu até cheguei a citar isso a questão de ser mais rápido, que lembro que até você mesmo questionou. Depois eu mesmo me questionei por tal definição. O que gostaria de saber é se realmente á mais rápido e por quê?! Caso realmente seja.

Comment: Não acho que tenha que responder porque a resposta seria a pergunta parte de uma premissa errada.

Comment: Como recebeu vários positivos e ninguém achou que deveria fechar eu resolvi responder, a resposta não é boa, mas a pergunta fraca com tão pouco sentido recebendo vários votos deve indicar alguma coisa.

Comment: Interessante porque nenhum dos artigos por si citados diz que é mais rápido.  Eles dizem `tão rápido quanto`

Comment: @BrunoCosta hmmmmmm... entendi.

Comment: A rapidez e performance nunca foram um objectivo da equipa que desenvolveu Kotlin. O objectivo, tanto quanto sei, foi sempre adicionar funcionalidades com o objectivo de simplificar a programação. Com o lançamento de Kotlin 2.0.0 vem a possibilidade de usar o compilador K2 que acelera, como efeito secundário, a compilação de código. Mas em qualquer caso, a velocidade a que correctamente nos podemos referir em relação ao Kotlin é simplemente a velocidade de produção e, no caso de K2, a velocidade de compilação. Performance é a mesma  porque em ambos os casos o que corre na JVM é bytecode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linguagens de programação não possuem velocidade. No máximo implementações possuem velocidade, mesmo assim depende de uma série de fatores. As bibliotecas costumam ser um fator muito mais importante para a performance.

Não consigo imaginar um motivo para Kotlin ser genericamente mais rápida. Pode ocorrer em algum ponto específico que implementações de Java ou a especificação exige um código mais ineficiente.

A biblioteca de Java é usada em Kotlin, então a performance é a mesma. É certo que existe algumas implementações específicas da biblioteca para Kotlin. Em geral o ganho é ser mais adequado para o uso com Kotlin, mas pode ter algum ganho também, mas eu não chamaria isto de ganho da linguagem, até porque aquilo pode ser usado em Java também.

Compiladores mais novos e desenvolvidos por uma quantidade menor de pessoas tendem a gerar código menos eficientes que outros mais populares, então novamente Java tende até ser mais rápida.

Quantidade visual de linhas não quer dizer muita coisa para medir velocidade. Na verdade tende a ocorrer o oposto e menos linhas pode significar menos velocidade porque pode estar escondendo algo que manualmente o programador poderia fazer de forma mais eficiente.

Aqui vou especular, mas pode ser até que o código gerado para Kotlin dificulte otimizações da JVM.

A pergunta parte de uma premissa errada.

Como complemento a minha experiência é que o compilador de Kotlin é muito lento.

Depois da resposta a pergunta foi editada com citaçaões.

1. Está escrito tão rápida, não mais rápida. Erro de interpretação.
2. Em nenhum momento diz que a linguagem é mais rápida. Diz que deve compilar rapidamente, o que é outra coisa, e não diz que é mais rápida que Java, mesmo assim minha experiência é que o compilador é bem mais lento. Erro de interpretação.
3. Fala muito genericamente sobre compilação incremental, nada mais. Erro de interpretação.

A premissa de Kotlin ser mais rápida que Java parece ser uma inferência sem fundamento do autor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Faz todo sentido.